# How to close a running windows OS program using a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, file-handling, file-management, file-manager

I'm making a simple GUI using Python 3.7.3 and tkinter to open and close windows applications. I'm not able to find a way to close a running program using an onscreen button. I need the 'close' button to do something else as well, hence the simply using 'x' button (which is next to the minimize and maximize) won't work for my case.

```
from tkinter import *
import os, subprocess

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def OpenCalc():    
    app1 = os.startfile("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe")

def CloseCalc():
    os.close(app1)
    # or
    # os.closefile("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe")

b1=Button(root, text="Open Calc", command=OpenCalc).pack()
b2=Button(root, text="Close Calc", command=CloseCalc).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I found the solution myself using trial and error. Here's what I did:

    os.system("taskkill /f /im calculator.exe")

Thing to note here is, even though you launch the Calculator app using calc.exe, the actual 'process' that windows runs is called calculator.exe. You need to use the process name to terminate it.
You can find the actual process name by first launching the app, the opening task manage, here exand the app you want, right click --> Go to details. This will show the exact process which is running.

Comment: Better use `proc = subprocess.Popen('calc.exe')` and then `proc.terminate()`.